# Outlook SMTP ignores the ReplyToList on my MailMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I have a contact form on my website.
In the past I sent the mails using my admin gmail account (with gmail smtp).
Now I have to switch to a professional account made on outlook.
Problem is that it now seems impossible to spoof another address into the reply header. If I reply on the mail it always get send to "info@xxx.be" instead of the address filled in on the contact form.

This is the code that used to work in the past.
Is there any way to make this code work again?

```
try
{
    var message = new MailMessage();

    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("info@xxx.be"));
    message.From = new MailAddress(from);
    message.ReplyToList.Clear();
    message.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(from));
    message.Subject = subject;
    message.Body = body;
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;

    var client = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587)
    {
        EnableSsl = true,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("info@xxx.be", "xxxxx")
    };
    client.Send(message);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: Why are you setting the `reply to` with the same value as the `from`?

Comment: Cause I want to make it look like the mail was sent by the customer (using the form) to the business address (info@xxx.be).
Since the From is hard to spoof i also include it in the ReplyToList so if i press reply on the mail it will at least sent it to the customer and not my own address (because that is the one that was used for the smtp server). But this doesn't seem to work when using outlook.com as smtp. The reply always refers to info@xxx.be.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a string here:

```
message.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(from));
```

Change the above code to read:

```
message.ReplyToList.Add(from);
```

MailAddressCollection.Add(...) takes a string as an argument, not a MailMessage. This is probably why it is ignoring it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144695(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Just tried it out and this doesn't work either.
Both are correct and work when using gmail smtp server but it doesnt work wen using outlook.com as smtp.

Comment: outlook.com may block this for security reasons, to stop their service being abused by spammers. Sorry I didn't spot that detail in the OP.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I couldn't find any official statement.
Shouldn't this be declared/specified somewhere?
I am curious if Office365 has the same behaviour.
I don't get how other sites manage to send these mails...